# How can I reinstall apt?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, apt, reinstall

**Hi!**
I deleted by mistake, the command apt and apt-get...

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04 TLS

Error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/apt: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory
```

How can I reinstall APT command?

Comment: In theory you could download the package `apt` manually and install it using `dpkg`. In this case you should make sure to download the package version that matches your OS version and architecture. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 16.04 is not supported anymore, so I don't know which package version(s) are compatible with this OS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt) page and look for the `apt` package, there you can download the binary .deb file depending on your processor architecture...

[image]

But consider that, the deb files have some dependencies... you have to install them too, for listing the package dependencies, use the dpkg, eg:

```
dpkg -I apt-armhf-blahblah.deb
```

if you deleted the `apt` package by itself, take a look at its log file in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, you can discover the name of packages that you removed.

**HINT 1: since the DPKG can't automatically install the dependencies, you have to install them one by on**e!

**HINT 2: that's recommended to remove your current OS and install the latest version because [this version will not receive any maintenance update anymore](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle).**